# Clear localstorage data from a remote server

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, local-storage

i have an automatic login system for my app compiled with phonegap build, when the app opens for the first time and you enter the correct username and password and it logs you in, it does auto login the subsequent times.

I save the username and password `onsubmit` of a button in the `localstorage` and the form action posts the data to the remote server for authentication.

Now the problem is once there's data in the `localstorage` the auto login action is fired which means if one should enter a wrong username and password for the first time, the user cannot re-type the right again since when the app opens and there is data in the localstorage the form action is fired and now you are on the remote server using the app. meaning there is no way of clearing the localstorage saved in the index of the app. Is there a way i can clear locally saved localstorage data from a remote server?

here's my script that saves into the localstorage and auto login

```
if (localEmail != null && localPwd != null) {

     $('#form1').submit();
  }

  // SAVE VARIABLES TO LOCAL STORAGE
  $('#form1').on('submit', function() {
    localStorage.setItem("eaddress", $email.val());
    localStorage.setItem("pwd", $password.val());
```

Comment: Why are you storing a password in localstorage, that is not secure?

Comment: User types in info -> Sends to server -> Server replies with either success or error. If success -> Store in locastorage. If error -> let user retry. (Don't save before you get an answer from your server.)

Answer (score 2):

For folks who are looking to clear localstorage (web browser, in the window obj) from the server side, include the Clear-Site-Data http header.

```
Clear-Site-Data: "storage"
```

More info here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Clear-Site-Data

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to work on the lógicas Narong sugested 2. You can use the .removeItem() of localstorage to remove the login